# Select the value from dropdown and show the selected values below in a table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm displaying the table by retrieving the data from MySQL DB and There are few columns which has a drop-down list which have check-box values.Now when I select the few values from the dropdown list , the backend PHP script should able to take those values and query DB to select data of those values and display on webpage.

Please guide me how to do this either in PHP or you can also guide me as autopostback concept or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a onchange event on the dropdown and everytime the change happens u can call ajax and send the **selected id** and fetch the information and show it...

Comment: Okay .. can you tell me if I can put a form element and this form will have the table displaying values. So now if i select few values from dropdown how can I display selected values below.

Comment: everytime u select the id while doing onchange . u can get the text of it using.... var value =  $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text(); and u can append it bellow wherever u want to.. using $('#div1').append(value);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some PHP and some jQuery (or just pure java script, if you wish).

In jQuery, you set up onChange event for your options list input.
When event occurs, you use Ajax to run PHP script with a parameter of value of form input. In PHP script you run some query into DB or whatever you need and return response. That response could be just what you need to print into your table. Then, in jQuery, you can make your table display that response PHP script returned.

Here, you may want to read this: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Okay .. can you tell me if I can put a form element and this form will have the table displaying values. So now if i select few values from dropdown how can I display selected values below.Can I achieve this only using php and html.If so How can I?

Comment: Well, you could use only php and html. The difference would be you need to reload all page after you submit all selected elements. On this page with table you would have to build that table using php and filling it with selected elements from dropdown. Also, you may want to use isSet() to check if there's at least one selected element.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

**first of all make a dropdown :**

```
 <select name="abc" id="dropdown" onChange="get-data()">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
 </select>
```

Here,we put a `onchange` event on the dropdown and everytime the change happens `ajax` function calls.i.e. `get-data()`.

**Function :**

```
<script>
    function get-data()
    {
        var option_value = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
        var dataString = 'value=' + option_value;

    // AJAX code to submit form.    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_results.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=html;
    }
    });
    return false;
    } 
</script>
```

Here, `get_results.php` is the page where you execute your query according to the values selected from the dropdown. and then show the result in the `div` named as `table`.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: For example, the code to display the table data is in php script.Now when i click on some checkbox , can the ajax send back the results to same php script where it queries the DB and displays the values? Will the code executes sequentially.

Comment: the ajax send back the results from `get_results.php` to the page from where you select the data from dropdown.